# Laravel 5 scope for selecting rows based on user role

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a timesheet application which I have written in Laravel 5.  I now want to select timesheets based on the user permissions (role).  I have 3 levels of user.

- User
- Admin
- Supervisor

A *Supervisor* supersedes a *User*.  *Admin* supersedes a *Supervisor*.

The admin user should be able to see ALL user timesheets.  The supervisor should only be able to see timesheets of users associated with them.  Users will only be abl to see their own timesheets.

I have the following method setup to select timesheets awaiting approval.  This method only works for the User level at the moment as I have added a `whereUserId` clause.

How can I make the following method work for all roles of user (admin, user, supervisor)?

```
/**
 * Load timesheets awaiting approval.
 *
 */
public function timesheetsAwaitingApproval() 
{
    return $this->timesheet->whereUserId($this->userid)->whereStatus('Submitted')->get();
}
```

Comment: Where is this timesheetsAwaitingApproval() method defined?

Comment: You have to make relationship with supervisor and user to know which users are associated with a supervisor.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the hasManyThrough relationship between your models to get the timesheets you need, check the [doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through). Of course, this will only work if you

Supervisor example

```
public function timesheets()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Timesheet::class', 'User::class', 'timesheet_id', 'user_id');
}

public function timesheetsAwaitingApproval() 
{
    return $this->timesheets->whereStatus('Submitted')->get();
}
```

Or something like that, thats just an idea that might work for you.